# Maxmind GeoLite2 pure javascript/html example

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, geolocation

Is there a way to use the only Javascript and html to print a text or variable based on the country in an if statement using Maxmind free GeoLite2, if it's possible then could you please give me a small example to do so.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Example like:

https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/tutorial/

https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-javascript-demo

Please check this link to more idea.

Comment: This tutorial is for the paid geoip2 service, i'm asking about the GeoLite2 free service

Comment: Please check this link 
https://ipstack.com/documentation
but some limit per api call